# Swift- custom UITableViewCell delegate to UIViewController only one protocol works

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

In the application, I have custom protocols that my UIViewController conforms to. I have a custom tableViewCell class and have UIImageView and UITextView in there. I set the cell's delegate to the UIViewController after dequeuing. However only one of the custom protocols makes the callback (imagepicker protocol).

```
protocol customProtocol1{
    func pickImage(myInt: Int)
}
protocol customProtocol2{
    func protocol2 (myInt: Int)
}

class controller1: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, customProtocol1, customProtocol2  {
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
        let cell = tableView.dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell",    forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableCellClass
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
   }
    func pickImage ( myInt: Int){
        print("This line prints")
   }

   func protocol2 (myInt: Int){
        print ("This line doesn't print")


   }
}
```

And here's the customTableCellClass code:

```
class CustomTableCellClass: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {
    var imageDelegate: customProtocol1?
    @IBAction func pickImage( sender: AnyObject) {
        imageDelagate?.pickImage(205)
    }

    var somethingElseDelegate: customProcotol2?
    @IBActon func clickOnButton( sender: AnyObject) {
        print("this line prints")
        somethingElseDelegate?.protocol2(2)
    }

   override func awakeFromNib(){
        super.awakeFromNib()
   }
}
```

My question is, why does the first protocol get callbacks but second does not?

Comment: Did you mean `cell.imageDelegate = self`? Where does `delegate` come from?

Answer (score 10):

From what I see in your code, you only set one delegate, change your code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
    let cell = tableView.dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell",    forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableCellClass
    cell.imageDelegate = self
    cell.somethingElseDelegate = self
    return cell
}
```

Comment: yea I just figured that out right now. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @EugeneTemlock Please accept my answer if you think it's correct answer :) Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your `custom cell` has two *delegate properties*, `imageDelegate` and `somethingElseDelegate`, but in your implementation of `tableView(tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` you only assign one property.

If you set both properties your implementation should work.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{ 
    let cell = tableView.dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableCellClass
    cell.imageDelegate = self
    cell.somethingElseDelegate = self
    return cell
}
```