# Perform a segue selection from a uicollectionview that is embedded in a tableview cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Currently we have a uicollectionview that is embedded in a tableview cell.  When the collection view cell is selected it's suppose to initiate a push segue to another view controller.  The problem is there is no option to perform the segue on the cell.  Is there a way around it?  Here is the cell:

```
class CastCell : UITableViewCell {

  var castPhotosArray: [CastData] = []

  let extraImageReuseIdentifier = "castCollectCell"
  let detailToPeopleSegueIdentifier = "detailToPeopleSegue"

  var castID: NSNumber?

  @IBOutlet weak var castCollectiontView: UICollectionView!

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    castCollectiontView.delegate = self
    castCollectiontView.dataSource = self
  }
}


extension CastCell: UICollectionViewDataSource {

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return castPhotosArray.count
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = castCollectiontView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: extraImageReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CastCollectionViewCell

    cell.actorName.text = castPhotosArray[indexPath.row].name     
    return cell
  }
}

extension CastCell: UICollectionViewDelegate {

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      self.castID = castPhotosArray[indexPath.row].id

     performSegue(withIdentifier: detailToPeopleSegueIdentifier, sender: self) //Use of unresolved identifier 'performSegue' error

    }
}


extension CastCell {
   func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let peopleVC = segue.destination as! PeopleDetailViewController

    peopleVC.id = self.castID
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is there is no option to perform the segue on the cell

There is no such thing as a "segue on a cell". A segue is from one view controller to another. `performSegue` is a UIViewController method. So you cannot say `performSegue` from within your CastCell class, because that means `self.performSegue`, and `self` is a UITableViewCell — which has no `performSegue` method.

The solution, therefore, is to get yourself a reference to the view controller that controls this scene, and call `performSegue` on that.

In a situation like yours, the way I like to get this reference is by walking up the responder chain. Thus:

```
var r : UIResponder! = self
repeat { r = r.next } while !(r is UIViewController)
(r as! UIViewController).performSegue(
    withIdentifier: detailToPeopleSegueIdentifier, sender: self)
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like its working but for some strange reason it looks like the prepareForSegue isn't being called.

Comment: Keep in mind that I have no knowledge of your storyboard. There might not be a segue coming from this view controller called `"detailToPeopleSegue"`. The `performSegue` call would then just fail silently. Check the storyboard carefully! Also try logging `r` afterwards and make sure we've got the right view controller.

Comment: sir how can u pass a value (like id) to the other viewcontroller using this ?

Comment: @danutha You can't. The "other view controlller" doesn't exist. But now the segue will be performed, `prepare(for:)` will be called on the first view controller, and now the first view controller can pass information to the second view controller — as usual.

Answer (score 1):

1: A clean method is to create a `delegate protocol` inside your `UITableViewCell` class and set the `UIViewController` as the responder.

2: Once `UICollectionViewCell` gets tapped, handle the taps inside the `UITableViewCell` and forward the tap to your `UIViewController` `responder` through `delegatation`.

3: Inside your `UIViewController`, you can act on the tap and perform/push/present whatever you want from there.

You want your `UIViewController` to know what is happening, and not call push/presents from "invisible" subclasses that should not handle those methods.

This way, you can also use the `delegate protocol` for future and other methods that you need to forward to your `UIViewController` if needed, clean and easy.

Comment: That sounds like a good way to do it unfortunately I'm not entirely sure how to create a protocol like that

Comment: @SwiftyJD I don't code in Swift so I dont want to make a mistake showing you code. But it is very easy once you get a grip of it , it takes like max 2 to 5minutes to set up everything I wrote above. Google for it , this might give you a hint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480831/swift-custom-uitableviewcell-delegate-to-uiviewcontroller-only-one-protocol-wor or https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=uitableview+custom+delegate+protocol+swift3&*

Comment: @SwiftyJD Once you create the delegate , don't forget to set the UIViewController as the responder in your cellForItemAtIndexPath method like : yourCell.delegate = self;