# Detect scrolling tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a tableview that each cell contains a collectionview.How can I detect corresponding cell when user scrolls a collection?

```
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if (lastContentOffset.x < (scrollView.contentOffset.x)) {

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "scrolledRight"), object: nil)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way should be to create a delegate like

```
protocol TableCellScrollDelegate {
   func didSrcoll(cell : UITableViewCell, offset : CGPoint)
}
```

In your TableViewCell Class, implements the `UIScrollViewDelegate` and then forward the message using protocol.

Comment: but the didselect function dosnt call ? what I did wrong?

Comment: when I set cell's delegate to self in cellForRowAtIndexPath i get an error !

Comment: I have custom tableview cell that using the protocol you suggested.so I should assign cell delegate to self in cellforrowat function.but it says   can't Cannot assign value of type 'GalleryViewControllera'(the class my tableview is) to type 'TableCellScrollDelegate?'

Comment: I followed this but I have error :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480831/swift-custom-uitableviewcell-delegate-to-uiviewcontroller-only-one-protocol-wor

Comment: class GalleryViewControllera : TableCellScrollDelegate { // }